# Freeware VirtualMachine software with snaphots feature

Tags: windows, gratis, virtual-machine

I use VirtualBox which has the snapshot feature. VirtualBox-guest has long loading times for Internet and hard disk. I will try it with Windows-guest as well. But with Vmware Workstation player I didn't have such problems, except the missing snapshot feature.

Is there some other freeware software, which also has the snapshot feature?

I use Windows as host system. I was thinking to use Linux/Debian as guest, but could be also Windows.

Comment: If I may ask what are you looking in something else that VirtualBox doesn't provide you?

Comment: It's because the VirtualBox-guest have long loading times for Internet and harddisk. I will try it with windows-guest as well. But with Vmware Workstation player i didn't have such problems, except the missing snapshot-feature.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "*has long loading times for Internet and hard disk*". What "internet" are you loading in your VM?

Comment: The loading time of opening websites and the systemtime the internet-browser takes, the icon of the harddisk and network seems busy, and the vm freezes then. I can't exactly say, which website or application hangs when I use the vm with virtualbox. And it is not every time, actually it seems okay, it is slower than the host, but it works.

Comment: VirtualBox is usually very good, so maybe your comparison between it and VMWare Player was on a machine (guest or host) with different specs?

Comment: Virtual Box should be a good program. I use the same Host for vmware player and virtual box. Maybe a benchmark should be do.

Comment: The problem of the slow vm-system, seemed to be the cause of using vm-network of virtualbox and vmware at the same time. By disabling or deleting one of these network interfaces, virtualbox or vmware, the problem disapeared. However there should be a setting option to allow both of it.